# Minhagim pertaining to the consumption of locust with other foods?

Tags: minhag, meat, fish, bugs

BS"D

So based on the concept that locust are the only other "meat" that is parve besides fish, do the same or similar Halakhic or even minhag based restrictions apply to it?
For instance its some peoples minhag not to eat fish and dairy together for the same reasoning as why people don't eat fowl and dairy.
And what about the custom of some to use differing cutlery for meat then that of fish, same apply to locust? 
ect.

I know that the general reasoning behind all the minhagim of fish being separate then other parve foods, in relation to meat, is from the odd Halakha that it makes for easy digestion and to not arouse medical concerns (Pesahhim 76b)

Obviously this question does not have a Halakhic source since Hhazal never ruled on it, but are there any minhagim or post authoritative rabbinic sources that speak on this matter?

I have asked a few members of various communities (mainly Eritreans, Temani, Syrians and Egyptians) who still eat locust and the only response i got was towards whether they eat the meat with dairy and its a mix between those that do and those that don't. 
Any help to feed my curiosity would be appreciated.

Comment: `For instance its some peoples minhag not to eat fish and dairy together` [Ben Ish Chai 2 Beha'alosecha 15](http://www.shechem.org/torah/benishhi/sheni/behaalot.html) says it's forbidden for everyone, because it could kill you.